# Bitbucket Issue Tracking Multiple Repositories

Tags: bitbucket, issue-tracking

I have several Bit repositories that I'd like to easily issue track on my dashboard. To do this, I am navigating to to Dashboard -> Issues -> setting FILTERS from 'Overview' to 'Watching'.

[image]

For my use, it is inconvenient to click 'Watching' every time I navigate into the issue tracking section. Because of this, I am wondering if there is any way to set the default FILTERS from 'Overview' to 'Watching'.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to do that at the moment, short of going directly to the "watching" view via URL (https://bitbucket.org/dashboard/issues?section=watching). You can add a feature request at https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues though.

Comment: Looks like I'll go with that url solution for now. Thanks